# Is it possible to create a view from external data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some csv files in my data lake which are being quite frequently updated through another process. Ideally I would like to be able to query these files through spark-sql, without having to run an equally frequent batch process to load all the new files into a spark table.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html), I'm unsure as all the examples show views that query existing tables or other views, rather than loose files stored in a data lake.

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if your csv is in S3 under the location `s3://bucket/folder`:

```scala
spark.sql(
"""
CREATE TABLE test2
(a string, b string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LOCATION 's3://bucket/folder'

"""
)
```

You have to adapt the fields tho and the field separators.
To test it, you can first run:

```scala
Seq(("1","a"), ("2","b"), ("3","a"), ("4","b")).toDF("num", "char").repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv("s3://bucket/folder")
```